# No debug_backtrace() support with Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've been having an issue migrating an existing codebase to ZF2.
I have an exception handler set up that generates an email with, among other things, a dump of debug_backtrace() and func_get_args(). It just adds to a string using print_r(debug_backtrace(), true) and print_r(func_get_args(), true).

It seems like this doesn't work for anything on ZF2. There seems to be some recursion going on. No matter how much memory I throw at it, it always crashes with a fatal error of allowed memory size being exhausted.

Is there a way to get the backtrace with ZF2, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can't you just call ->getTrace() on the exception??

Comment: or if you are just getting it to turn it into a string then `Exception::getTraceAsString();`

Comment: I had a similar issue with a backtrace on ZF2. I logged it to a text file and the backtrace of a very simple script was over 40MB. There is really a lot going on in ZF2 and this is also the reason why I will go away from it for MVC applications.

Comment: thanks Orangepill, Exception::getTraceAsString() seems to do the trick. i guess i can't mark your comment as an answer, so if you want to add as an answer, i can give you credit.

Comment: So after using Exception::getTraceAsString() for a little while, I'm realizing that it truncates argument strings if they get too long.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up backing out of the ZF2 migration, but I'll add Orangepill's comment here as an answer.

The workaround at the time was to use Exception::getTraceAsString(). The downside was that it didn't supply as much info as debug_backtrace() & func_get_args(), but at least gave us SOME info rather than crashing.